# Code analysis runs on biztalk 2009 generated code

Tags: biztalk, code-analysis

Did anyone find out a way so that code analysis does not run or is suppressed on biztalk generated code?

I am having all sorts of problems with warnings as errors set to true (5000 + errors on *.xsd.cs)

Comment: I had a problem with my stylecop settings file. Sorry for wasting peoples time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just disable code analysis for your BizTalk projects. Its under Project Properties => Code Analysis

Alternatively, you can replace these with the BizTalk Cop rules - http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/11/14/introducing-biztalkcop.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I actually want code analysis on my projects.

Comment: What I mean is I can'd understand why style/fx cop thinks my generated code is user code.

Comment: Thanks for responding by the way.